# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS does not boot with enabled IDE controller

Tags: boot, dual-boot, asus

I cannot boot ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the IDE controller enabled. Similar problems (with ASUS mainboards) were described in the threads

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1662883, and 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1891554

I have a dualboot system (Win7) and installed ubuntu via USB, I have an ASUS M4A88TD-V EVO/USB3.
After the installation, ubuntu could not boot. There was simply a violett screen or only a blinking cursor.
So I used noplymouth to see what happened and it stopped at the two IDE devices (DVD drives).
I tried a BIOS update and booting with "all_generic_ide" (I thought this may help since it has to do with IDE),
but only disabling the IDE controller in the BIOS helped.

Is there maybe a known solution to this problem, which apparently has to do with these ASUS mainboards?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) that matches your architecture

And burn it to CD or make a bootable USB out of it (according to the instructions at the link above).

Boot your computer using the disk, and run the boot-repair program.

Comment: I tried the boot-repair-disk, but it didn't help. I even had to boot it in fail safe mode because otherwise it would not boot as well. But running the repairing program (in fail safe mode) did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your motherboard has Linux support from the manufacturer. [at least they made LAN driver for Linux](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A88TDV_EVOUSB3/#support) So if nothing works you may ask them.

Also it looks like there are lot of BIOS updates for this MOBO, so please update to the latest one. And also you should try the latest kernel (which version are you using now?)

Comment: I have the latest BIOS update and also the latest kernel (i checked for updates).
Maybe I'll ask ASUS or I'll simply try a SATA drive, if IDE does not work.

Comment: @Rimar That would be the best. Send them the links of the similar problems, and if they do propose a solution don't forget to put the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, also exact same Asus MB M4A88TD-V EVO USB 3 (Phenemon II Black 6 core) and after looking at Ubuntu loading drivers, it would hang at TSSTCorp line.  Did exactly as you, went into BIOS and disabled IDE onboard devices and it boots nicely.  Reading some post somewhere, there was an off the cuff remark that Ubuntu was quirky about how you set the CD/DVD player Master Slave jumpers.

Eureka!  I set mine from master to cable select and issue is gone.  Boots up rather nicely.

So I have one SATA DVD drive and one IDE DVD drive (only kept it because it is a Light Scribe drive) with the IDE drive set to cable select and the master cable plug (one on the end) in the drive.  Solved problem.

Sorry, it didn't ! when I booted again, the same problem with black screen and hang on the grub restore at TSST line.  So it must have been disconnecting the computer to switch the jumper and next I tried switching off at the power supply for enough time to clear the MB and then tried boot and was successful and the DVD's are functional again.  Go figure.

So to boot Umbutu, I will need to either switch off or disconnect power supply or figure out what is happening.  For now, it switching off power supply, good that I have long arms.

Need to look and see if Light Scribe has Linux version